# Trying to open a new fancybox within a fancybox using "fancybox-hidden"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, fancybox

Trying to open a new fancybox within a fancybox using "fancybox-hidden"? Using the Sirius Wordpress theme. My code is below. Any hints would be great.

```
            <img src="<?php echo $small_image_url[0]; ?>" alt="" class="portfolio_img"/>

        <!-- MATTSTER ADDED NEW ACTION TAG FOR LIGHTBOX AND NEW POST EXCERPT -->
        <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-fancybox-group="fancybox-thumb" href="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>">
            <div class="mask">
                <div class="mask_frame">
                    <div class="mask_image_content">
                        <div class="mask_image_content_frame">
                            <h6><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h6>
                            <span><?php echo strip_tags(pp_get_the_excerpt($portfolio_ID)); ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div class="mancy">
        <a class="fancybox-thumb" rel="gallery-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-fancybox-group="fancybox-thumb"><img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" /></a>
        </div>
```